# How to handle lazy loading?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, lazy-loading

In this part of my program, I am trying to get all links to the images on the webpage. However, these pictures are lazy-loaded. Even though it isn't like: pictures appear when scrolling down, the pictures are already here. Each page has 30 products on it. Scrolling down the page doesn't do the magic either. How can I handle this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


url= 'https://www.bookdepository.com/category/2/Art-Photography/browse/viewmode/all'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('blabla')

driver.get(url)


a = 1
while a != 100:
    try:                                                                                                                                                                   
        link_picture = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div["+ str(a) +"]/div[1]/a/img"))).get_attribute('src')                                                                                                    
        print(link_picture)
    except:
        print("\nno products left")
        #e = a - 1
        #print(a)
        #print(e)
        break
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: are you trying to get the product img of each item ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the page is loaded via `JavaScript` which is rendered `internally` on the `host` itself once the page loads, Therefore the [Lazy-Load](https://www.sitepoint.com/five-techniques-lazy-load-images-website-performance/) will be a very bad approach to handle with `selenium` via `Implicit, Explicit, & Fluent` Wait in `Selenium WebDriver`, That's will take a huge time.

We can just use `requests` and `bs4` with a tricky way. we will collect the `img` `IDs#` and then we will matching them to be typically as the one on the site.

> Note: I've checked manually and i can confirm for you that the `token` id of `CloudFront` for that site is `static` which is `d1w7fb2mkkr3kw`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.bookdepository.com/category/2/Art-Photography/browse/viewmode/all")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

url = "https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/"

for item in soup.findAll("meta", itemprop="isbn"):
    item = item.get("content")
    print(
        f"{url}{item[:4]}/{item[4:8]}/{item}.jpg")
```

Output:

```
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/4087/9781408708989.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/5098/9781509853311.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/7522/9780752265629.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/1410/9780141014081.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/2500/9781250038821.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/1410/9780141035796.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/8499/9781849941679.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/0995/9780099539551.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/4087/9781408711705.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9788/8837/9788883701153.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/7475/9780747568766.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/8609/9781860969423.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/4711/9781471157790.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/5098/9781509829477.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/7515/9780751535662.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/5005/9780500513606.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/4088/9781408890769.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/8771/9780877180128.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9788/8837/9788883705601.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/4722/9781472200341.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/8478/9781847807717.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/8609/9781860969430.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/3409/9780340936177.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/4862/9780486254500.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/7160/9780716022237.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/0994/9780099457046.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/4521/9781452106557.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9780/2411/9780241184837.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/7423/9781742372389.jpg
https://d1w7fb2mkkr3kw.cloudfront.net/assets/images/book/mid/9781/8499/9781849942850.jpg
```

> Update:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.bookdepository.com/category/2/Art-Photography/browse/viewmode/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("img", class_="lazy"):
    print(item.get("data-lazy"))
```